# Can I use `µ` as a JavaScript variable name?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Valid Characters for JavaScript Variable Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

I know that the [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) specification says I can use *µ* (Greek lowercase Mu), and I have tested on a couple of browsers, but is it rock solid? Will it work with all browsers? What could be the pitfalls?

Technically I don't expect it is any different than jQuery using `$` as a variable name - is there a technical difference?

Comment: Yes you can use µ, all unicode letters are allowed – this thread might be of interrest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names

Comment: This validator might also help: http://mothereff.in/js-variables#%E2%98%83

Comment: More to the point: should you use it? I think not. What's wrong with `mu`?

Comment: Please don't, my keyword can't input `µ` :(

Comment: @xdazz what keyboard/os are you using? Can you not get it with `Alt Gr+m`?

Comment: @Billy Moon: it is OS-dependent. For instance, I mapped my compose key to the Windows button, and have to do `compose key + m + u` (m and u in sequence) to get `µ`. French keyboards, for instance have a `µ` key for reasons only few can understand... It is not really a problem of not being able to input it, but rather a problem of not being practical to have a variable called `µ`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use it.

In example:

```
var π = Math.PI;
```

as well as [Unicode escape sequences](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode).

Basically, the variable in JavaScript can be anything that's valid according to ECMAScript 5.1 and Unicode 6.1.

Here is some online [JavaScript variable name validator](http://mothereff.in/js-variables).

For the references, [this page is for documenting the differences between ES5 specification and the requirements for ECMAScript implementations in web browsers](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Web_ECMAScript#Identifiers).

Comment: I need to know if it will work in all browsers, including mobile devices, and server side javascript etc... not whether some characters can be used on some browsers.

Comment: All browsers should have ECMAScript compability, so it should. If not, it's a bug then. Most of the mobiles using Safari or Opera, so they have the same implementations. So why it should work different. Why somebody should implement some limitations which are nowhere defined. If this works for IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari, it'll work everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

No, there aren't any "real" technical differences. *Almost* all Unicode letters are allowed as variable names in JavaScript. Check out [this great write-up](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers) for more information.

However, some Unicode characters use more bytes, so ASCII are perhaps the way to go anyway.

Comment: That writeup explains that all unicode can not be used - and that javascript uses UTF-8, not unicode.

Comment: Well at least categories of unicode, or UTF-16 (USC-2).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Here are references that support that claim

- *[Valid JavaScript variable names in ES5](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers)*
- *<s>http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/learning-javascript/javascript-datatypes-variables.html</s>*

Comment: The second link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a generic page.